# javascript: фильтрация строк с помощью маски

Tags: javascript, строки, typescript, инспекция-кода

стоит задача - есть маска-фильтр (строка) и строка слов (ФИО), требуется определить хотя бы одно из слов в строке покрывается маской, т.е. совпадает ли маска с началом слова (без учёта регистра слов)

написал такой работающий код:

```
// применить фильтр
const words: Array<string> = obj.value.split(" ");

const filterPrepared: string = this.state.filter.toLowerCase().trim();

let isFiltered: boolean = false;

for (const word of words) {

    const wordPrepared: string = word.substring(0, filterPrepared.length).toLowerCase();

    if ((word.length >= filterPrepared.length) && (filterPrepared.localeCompare(wordPrepared) === 0))
        isFiltered = true;
}
```

все хорошо работает, но такой вопрос - не слишком ли сложно ли, может в JS есть нормальные встроенные средства, чтобы сделать все более коротко и красиво?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения с модификатором `i`. Тогда поиск будет регистронезависимым. А чтобы искало только в начале слов добавьте к фильтру конструкцию `(^| )`. Что будет означать искать или с начала строки, или с пробела

```js
const filter = 'ABC';
const testWords = [
  'abc def',
  'ab abcdef',
  'ab deabc'
];

for (let i = 0; i < testWords.length; i++) {
  const isFiltered = testWords[i].match(new RegExp('(^| )' + filter, 'i')) !== null;
  console.log(testWords[i], isFiltered);
}
```

Или по совету [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/)

```js
const filter = 'ABC';
const filterTest = new RegExp('(^| )' + filter, 'i');

const testWords = [
  'abc def',
  'ab abcdef',
  'ab deabc'
];

for (let i = 0; i < testWords.length; i++) {
  const isFiltered = filterTest.test(testWords[i]);
  console.log(testWords[i], isFiltered);
}
```

Comment: вместо `match` лучше `test` - он сразу `boolean` возвращает

Comment: каждый раз когда регулярки использовать приходится - это как магия какая-то :)))

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо. Как-то не сообразил сразу

Answer (score 1):

Для определения того, что одна строка начинается с другой можно воспользоваться методом [`.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Для проверки наличия в массиве элемента, удовлетворяющего какому-либо условию можно воспользоваться методом [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
let isFiltered: boolean = words.some(word => word.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterPrepared))
```